# Change PowerShell object property names, retaining values

Tags: powershell

I have an object that looks like this.

```
$test = {
"displayName": "Testname"
"userAge": 22
}
```

I have an array that looks like this.

```
$friendlyNames = ["Display name", "User age"]
```

The way this is set up the $friendlyNames array index will always match with the object property order.
Is it possible to automatically replace this and end up with a object that looks like this?

```
$test = {
"Display name" = "Testname"
"User age" = 22
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible but, seems like you're defining your variables as you would do in python. Is this just for demonstration? What is the object type of your first object?

Comment: the usual way would be to use `Select-Object` with calculated properties. ///// **_however, you should avoid putting spaces or other "non-standard" chars in property or parameter names._** it adds the [utterly needless] need to wrap those names in quotes to allow one to use them. ///// **_if at all possible, DO NOT cause yourself problems that way._*** [*grin*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# The sample input object.
$test = [pscustomobject] @{
  displayName = "Testname"
  userAge = 22
}

# The array of new property names.
$friendlyNames = 'Display name', 'User age'

# Use an ordered hashtable as a helper data structure
# to store the new property names and their associated values as
# name-value pairs.
$oht = [ordered] @{}; $i = 0
$test.psobject.Properties.ForEach({
  $oht[$friendlyNames[$i++]] = $_.Value
})

# Convert the ordered hashtable to an object ([pscustomobject])
$testTransformed = [pscustomobject] $oht
```

Outputting `$testTransformed` yields (tabular formatting is applied by default, because the object has 4 or fewer properties; pipe to [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) to see each property on its own line):

```
Display name User age
------------ --------
Testname           22
```

Note:

- PowerShell exposes `.psobject` on any object as a rich source of reflection, and `.psobject.Properties` returns a collection of objects describing an object's public properties, each of which has `.Name` and `.Value` properties.
- Using an (ordered) [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) is an efficient way to iteratively create an (ordered) collection of key-value pairs, which can later be converted to a *custom object* simply by casting to `[pscustomobject]`.

  - In fact, the custom-object *literal* syntax (`[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`) suggests just that (as used to construct `$test` above), but note that this is *syntactic sugar* in that it results in *direct* (more efficient) construction of a `[pscustomobject]` instance.

Comment: That was absolutely brillliant, thank you!

I am aware that doing this is not the most effective way, and the data structure isnt great.
This helped me get by, and I had no clue you could iterate over the properties as well - very smart.

Have a great day!